# Empty php script fails when called with specific arguments

Tags: php, forms, field, http-status-code-404, varchar

I have a webserver hosted for free at atspace.com with an empty (literally, just empty) php script named test_empty.php in it.

When I call it with any arguments

```
myserver/test_empty.php?random_string
```

as expected it loads a blank page.

But in the specific case where I call it like that:

```
myserver/test_empty.php?random_string_containing_varchar
```

it redirects me to a 404 page.

Try it here - the first one works, the other doesn't:

http://playerdatabase.atspace.eu/test_empty.php?anything_you_want_to_write_is_ok

http://playerdatabase.atspace.eu/test_empty.php?unless_it_contains_VARCHAR

Since I'm developing software for different clients I want them to be able to use atspace as a host and I'd rather not find a custom workaround for this issue.

Any ideas? It's driving me nuts!

PS: I don't know how this plays in but this only happens in the FREE version of atspace. If I host the script in a paid account, nothing like that happens.

I already contacted their customer support but to no avail.

Comment: you've probably got a stupid/moronic/assinine security system that looks for sql-related keywords and assumes you're doing an sql injection attack. You can play with it and try other things, like `drop` and `select` and `insert` and whatnot.

Comment: @Marc You're right, it's an sql injection protection.. I spent my whole day on this thing..! But Why protect against "VARCHAR" ??

It's not like I'm calling
[link]playerdatabase.atspace.eu/test_empty.php?username=my_name;DROP TABLE users;

Comment: because people can't be arsed to fix their code, so they slap on useless bandaids and ignore the blood soaking through them. and of course, maybe it's a shared server and they're assuming that some of the users are really this stupid and will have code like `exec($_GET['killme'])` all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marc yep, that was it :)

Their support team let me know it's all due to list of blacklisted strings in an allmighty MOD_Security file that no one is allowed to touch ;)

What I still don't get is what's their problem with "VARCHAR" specifically - the other variable types are considered safe :P